# raspberry pi relay switch to ouput bulbs/other devices diagram

Tags: raspbian, relay

I'm new to raspberry pi, need some advise on the raspberry pi 2 to relay switch diagram which output to bulbs/other devices. The attach screenshot only connects from the pi to relay switch, but stuck on the output.. [image]

Comment: the blue and green output lines are connected to one side of your power supply and the matching pole of the device you are controlling. So for example ground from the power supply to the relay (green wire) then (blue wire) to ground of the device. Note you should not power the device connected to the green and blue wires from the Pi.